# Android horizontal carousel RecyclerView disappears

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-imageview, android-glide

I have a vertical RecyclerView and one of its elements is horizontal RecyclerView which is an image carousel. However, when I do adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() second time on vertical RecyclerView, all images in horizontal RecyclerView become invisible (their height is 0).

Each carousel image item:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
```

Also, I am using glide in order to download images. And I see that images are downloaded and ImageView has downloaded image, but somehow its height becomes 0.

This is how it looks in the beginning:
[image]

This is how it looks after second notifyDataSetChanged:
[image]

Comment: You should use fixed height in this case.

Comment: @Khemraj unfortunately, I can't because there are different images with different ratios

Comment: If you are setting items in RecyclerView, then there should be some minimum height at least?

Comment: Why do you call notifyDataSetChanged?

Comment: @mTak when you use pull to refresh all data on screen should be updated

Comment: You mean refresh all data in recyclerview, isn't it?

Comment: @mTak yes. Sorry for this

Answer (score 0):

You can try multiple options:
1. Set fix height of image.
2. Maybe you are setting image in some if condition in adapter, handle that else condition also because adapter is reusing the items.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Widget instead of the ImageView:

```
public class ScaleWidthImageView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView {

    public ScaleWidthImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ScaleWidthImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ScaleWidthImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        if (getScaleType() == ScaleType.FIT_XY) {
            final Drawable image = getDrawable();
            if (image == null) {
                setMeasuredDimension(0, 0);
            } else {
                int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
                int height = width * image.getIntrinsicHeight() / image.getIntrinsicWidth();
                setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
            }
        } else {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }
}
```

Then just use it on the XML like this:

```
<ScaleWidthImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

This widget makes the Image height dynamic depending on it's aspect ratio (which is what I assume you want).

Comment: the problem is that I don't have drawable in the beginning. Glide downloads it asynchronously. But, because drawable is null, dimensions are also 0

Comment: Do you mean you want to have an image there while Glide is downloading the actual image? Try using Glide's [placeholder](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/placeholders.html) feature.

Comment: no, I mean your code executes while glide is downloading image and therefore the size is still 0

Comment: @RustamIbragimov I don't know how else to explain so, here, I did a sample project where my widget works: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/80cb9cb4eff042d94edde3df9bee587020180720144436/27e8bb343addd1c173eeb4c24a650b0a20180720144436/96c56f